# Changing between 2 images with a right click at 1 button

Tags: vb.net

I have 2 images at my resources(**cat.png** and **dog.png**).
I want to know how could i change a button's background image between the 2 images when i am right clicking on it. Here is an example :

When i am right clicking the button, the button's image is cat and when i am right clicking again it changes to dog.

here is my code that doesn't work :

```
Private Sub btn1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles btn1.MouseDown
    If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then
        btn1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cat
        btn1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    End If
    If ((e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) And (Not btn1.BackgroundImage Is Nothing)) Then
        btn1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.dog
        btn1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    End If
End Sub
```

The cat is showing but when i am right clicking again nothing happens.

(sorry for my bad english :P )
Thanks!

Comment: You need a form-level boolean variable (`CatShowing`?). When the first block executes, test whether CatShowing is true. If so, show the dog and set CatShowing to false. The next time, because CatShowing is false, you show the cat and set CatShowing to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know how to clearly write a logic.Here I think no need to write second if statement.

So below check is sufficient to determine if cat then show dog else show cat.

```
If (e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right) Then
        If((btn1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cat) Or (btn1.BackgroundImage IsNot Nothing))  Then  'check for cat or no image
        btn1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.dog        ' set dog
        Else
        btn1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cat        'set cat
        End If
        btn1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch       'in any case only stretch once
End If
```

Also I would say to change not nothing check like below:

```
btn1.BackgroundImage IsNot Nothing
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it is detecting an error at < _cat_  / nothing>

Comment: @Biller You need to write actual syntax there.I have written a pseudo code in <>.Updated now.